# angular-fontawesome + FaIconLibrary + Angular + Storybook.js = :(

Tags: angular, font-awesome, storybook, angular-fontawesome

Simply would like to use angular-fontawesome with Storybook.js as a library (FaIconLibrary). In the following documentation https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/usage/icon-library.md#using-the-icon-library i'm to add a property to the constructor. Only in the Storybook.js file (index.stories.ts) I see no way to add anything to the constructor because it's not there. Anyone resolve this or have a good work around? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

One option is to use Angular's [`APP_INITIALIZER`](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) function to execute arbitrary code when storybook is loaded. In this particular case you can configure `FaIconLibrary` with the necessary icons during the app initialisation process.

Let's assume you have the below component which uses `fa-icon` and you want to use it inside the story book:

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-detail',
  template: `
    <h1>
      <fa-icon icon="user"></fa-icon>
      {{ fullName }}
    </h1>
    <p>Full name: {{ fullName }}</p>
  `,
})
export class UserDetailComponent {
  @Input()
  fullName: string;
}
```

In a story book for this component you can provide an `APP_INITIALIZER` in the [`moduleMetadata`](https://www.learnstorybook.com/intro-to-storybook/angular/en/screen/) call. This code will be executed when storybook is loaded and will configure `FaIconLibrary`:

```js
import { APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { FaIconLibrary, FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { faUser } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { moduleMetadata, storiesOf } from '@storybook/angular';
import { UserDetailComponent } from '../app/user-detail.component';

storiesOf('User Detail', module)
  .addDecorator(
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [ FontAwesomeModule ],
      declarations: [ UserDetailComponent ],
      // The key bit is the providers array below.
      providers: [
        {
          provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
          useFactory: (iconLibrary: FaIconLibrary) => {
            return async () => {
              // Add the necessary icons inside the initialiser body.
              iconLibrary.addIcons(faUser);
            };
          },
          // When using a factory provider you need to explicitly specify its 
          // dependencies.
          deps: [ FaIconLibrary ],
          multi: true,
        },
      ],
    }),
  )
  .add('default', () => {
    return {
      template: `<app-user-detail [fullName]="fullName"></app-user-detail>`,
      props: {
        fullName: 'John Doe',
      },
    };
  });
```

The full code can also be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/devoto13/fa-storybook).